# Sighting in a Rifle without firing a shot

Tags: guns, shooting, rifles

I was wondering if there is a way to sight in a rifle scope without firing a shot.

There are some reasons why I think it would useful to be able to do this. One depending on the scope you may have to sight it in often especially if you are carrying it around daily. 2 To conserve ammo and 3 To do it silently

I have a scope that has the traditional bullseye crosshair and then has triangle markings for every 100 yards below the crosshair. I have a laser bore sight.

So my thought was I have a piece of paper with markings on it or some kind of pre marked target and put it a certain reasonable distance away say 10-25 yards.  I'm sure there is some kind of math that would allow you to extrapolate the bullet drop to match the crosshair and the 100 yard triangles and be able to put those marking on the target.

Basically you use the laser bore sight to sight in the rifle at 25 yards directly on the bullseye and then adjust it to where the 100 yard triangles and match the bullet drop marking on the target.

Does something like this exist? I know it wouldn't be perfect but maybe it would be good enough.

Maybe the above is a stupid question.

Does sighting it in at 25 yards with a laser bore sight automatically line up the 100 yard triangles?

Comment: You end up firing lots of shots and you need a good scope, but [this is how it's done](http://americanshootingjournal.com/carlos-hathcock-method-of-sighting-in-a-rifle/). :)

Comment: there are factors influencing bullet trajectory that only come into play when a bullet is forced through the bore, so a laser bore sight can only ever tell you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bore sight will get you close, but it's not perfect and you will want to shoot real bullets to test your aim afterwards. If you bore sight it at 25 yards it should be on paper at 100 yards and you can make small adjustments from there.

As for calculating how much it will drop over distance/ be pushed by the wind there are [ballistic calculators](https://www.federalpremium.com/ballistics-calculator) or phone apps that will do all of the math for you.

Finally, if you are having to sight in regularly, there is probably something wrong with your scope mount and you should see about getting it tightened.